# Matplotlib: Error bars missing line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot something, but the output is not like I wish. I want the red lines like on my picture and I didn't find an argument at the documentation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
files = ['N30.dat', 'N40.dat', 'N50.dat', 'N60.dat', 'N70.dat', 'N80.dat']
N = 30

plot_list_x = []
plot_list_y = []

for fname in files:
    data = np.loadtxt(fname)
    x = [1 for _ in range(10)]
    N += 10

    # mean
    mean = data.mean()
    plt.plot(N, mean, '.')

    plot_list_x.append(N)
    plot_list_y.append(mean)

    # standard derivation
    sd = 0
    for i in data:
        sd += math.pow(i - mean, 2)
    sd = math.sqrt(sd/(N-1))

    # standard error
    se = sd/math.sqrt(N)

    plt.errorbar(N, mean, yerr=sd, fmt='_', ecolor='g', capthick=2)

plt.plot(plot_list_x, plot_list_y, 'g-')

plt.xticks([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])
plt.yticks([0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])

ax.set_title('Airline Streaming')
ax.set_xlabel('count of clients')
ax.set_ylabel('packet loss')
plt.show()
```

I want this, but I got the picture without the red lines.

[image: desired output]

Comment: [`capsize`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-errorbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary setting for obtaining "caps" at all is the `capsize` argument (see the docs for [`errorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar)), whose value is in points.

In your case the change would be on this line:

```
    plt.errorbar(N, mean, yerr=sd, fmt='_', ecolor='g', capthick=2, capsize=10)
```

Note that extra keyword arguments to `plt.errorbar` are passed for the formatting of the caps.